# Firebase + iOS: Receiving stale data using observeSingleEvent without using isPersistence = true

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently use `observeSingleEvent` to fetch data periodically in our game. It seems that the client is receiving stale data at times while using this method. From what I have read, I believe this should only happen if `isPersistence = true`, which is not the case. Is this still expected behavior? Shouldn't I receive fresh data each time I query? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: More detailed query:

```
for levelNumber in 1...numberOfLevels
{
    ref.child(pathToLevelData + "/" + levelNumber).queryOrderedByValue().queryStarting(atValue: 
                 highScore+1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children
        {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    guard let value = snap.value as? Int else { return }

            // Process value, but it is not always fresh data from Firebase

        }
       })
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your question include the minimal, **complete** information to reproduce the problem with. A single line is not enough to determine what's going on.

Comment: If you replace the `observeSingleEvent` with a regular observe, does this same closure get triggered twice in a row (once with the stale value, and once with the up to date value)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No it does not, it just triggers once with fresh data.

Comment: In that case it is very unlikely that this is related to a stale cache, and looking for that seems like a red herring. Without disk caching it should be quite hard to get stale values from Firebase, so I'm not sure what could be causing it for you. You might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_) and check if that shows a hint of what's going on.

Comment: I am with @FrankvanPuffelen on this. I've never had Firebase return stale data with persistence off. My guess is that either theres some issue with the *value* var in code, or what's in the node is different than what you expect. Can you include  your Firebase structure as text? To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will need to put together a sample project to show this. It is is repeatedly happening in my project. Just returned a stale value as of ~30 minutes ago a few times in a row. Is there a limit to how often you can get new data with observeSingleEvent? We are refreshing fairly frequently, sometimes within 5-10 minutes, and with many queries (100+). Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no limit: if you use `observeSingleEvent`, the client first checks if it has the state for that location in memory, it then gets the state from the server, passes the snapshot to your callback, and then forgets about it.

Comment: I've run your code probably 500 times today with changing values each time and it didn't present any stale data once over the run. However, we don't know the structure of your Firebase or what you're expecting to get out of it. It's possible another client is *writing* data to that node that makes it appear stale. I think we need to see your structure, as mentioned above, and perhaps a use case.

Comment: @Jay, sorry for the delay in response and thank you for taking the time to test. I found in the code that I was sometimes writing to the node while simultaneously reading from it, which lines up with what you said here. Upon fixing this the problem went away.